# IE8 ExtJs4 issue

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, extjs4

I have developed a web application using ExtJs4.0.7.
The application is working fine in firefox, chrome, IE 8,9 on Windows Xp,7.
But it is not working on IE8 Windows xp sp3.
Also in IE8 developer tool console there are no errors.

Has anyone faced these issues for Window xp sp3 and have solution for the same. Following is the IE version I am having on my Windows xp sp3 machine -

IE- 8.0.6001.18702

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try working with `ext-dev.js` file instead of `ext.js` or `ext-all.js` and probably you would see the errors in the console if any in the extjs framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check carefully your JS code for unnecessary commas, something like that (see one after value2):

```
object: {
   prop1: value,
   prop2: value2,
}
```

Chrome, FF and Safari don't care, but IE usually stops working.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply...i have checked all the json that are used on that page...and there are no trailing commas over there, if they were there then atleast i should have seen the error console but i am not able to see those errors also...